# Before getting Undefined index error and after clicked on button error goes off in PHP

Tags: php, session

I have set the session which is working but If I refresh the page then I am getting error

> Undefined index: email_error

and if I clicked on submit button then it is working. I also set the empty but not working.

There is some issue in session.

**php**

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION['email_error']="";

            if (empty($_SESSION['email'])) {
                    $_SESSION['email_error']="email is empty";  
                    header('location:index.php');
            }

    }

 ?>
```

**HTML**

```
<?php
session_start();

$email_error="";
$email_error=$_SESSION['email_error'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="process.php" method="post">
     <span class="error"><?php echo $email_error;?></span>
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
<?php
session_destroy();
 ?>
```

Comment: The solution for this is removing the session_destroy(); line. This will clear your session.

Comment: Sorry Mr.Sander, I deleted my session_destory() from HTML file but still getting error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: No major here.you are not setting any values to that.do like $_SESSION['email_error']='';

Comment: Check if your $_SESSION['email_error'] is being set.

Comment: Yes Mr.lalithkumar, I haven't set any value for that. If I clicked in submit button then it will assign the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like:

```
<?php
session_start();

$email_error="";
$email_error=isset($_SESSION['email_error'])?$_SESSION['email_error']:'';
?>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will work for you @Narendra Verma

Comment: Yes, Mr. Lalit Kumar It working for me now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm using ternary operator with isset..Isset will check the the value has been set to the variable or not.if set ? will come first one otherwise it will go to next one after :

Comment: Cool!! Thanks for your information. I got it now. Upvote from my side.

Answer (score 1):

The `session_destroy()` deletes your current session, so each refresh is a new session.

`session_destroy` is for deleting a session

for more info: [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

Comment: I know session_destory()  will delete the session but without creating my session it's getting error

Comment: you are wrong for logout you don't use `session_destroy()` function, you can use unset() for logout. like unset($_SESSION['loginid]);

Comment: you have to create a session to be able to save data to it, but you do not have to destroy it. destroy means you delete it, with its contents

Comment: I haven't created session till now. If I clicked on submit then it will create the session. right?

Answer (score -1):

remove session_destroy(); from last then it will work.

Comment: Yes I deleted but still getting error Notice: Undefined index: email_error in C:\xampp\htdocs....

Comment: @NarendraVerma it's a notice, not error. you can turn off error reporting